# Can't find or install tkinter

Tags: 16.04, python3, tkinter

I have a problem with the tkinter module in Ubuntu 16.04. It needs to be loaded to run a python3.6 program, but it can't be found:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/declooptor", line 11, in <module>
     load_entry_point('declooptor==0.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'declooptor')() File
 "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
 line 487, in load_entry_point
     return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
 line 2728, in load_entry_point
     return ep.load()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
 line 2346, in load
     return self.resolve()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
 line 2352, in resolve
     module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)   File
 "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/declooptor-0.1.0-py3.6.egg/declooptor/detector.py",
 line 39, in <module>   File
 "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line
 2374, in <module>
     switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 207, in switch_backend
     backend_mod = importlib.import_module(backend_name)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py",
 line 1, in <module>
     from . import _backend_tk   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tkinter as Tk ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

But when I type `sudo apt install python3-tk` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-tk is already the newest version (3.5.1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

`which python3.6` returns `/usr/bin/python3.6`

I have checked the folders `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`, `/usr/lib/python3.5` and `/usr/lib/python3.6` but there is no `tkinter` folder, though they may have another name now?

Does somebody know what to do?

Comment: The result is `/usr/bin/python3.6`. I have done what karel suggests but it did't work. The error message is still the same.

Comment: It still does not work :(

Comment: Ok, so to answer my own question: I unsinstalled and reinstalled python.